# How to find missing classes in a webapp running in JBoss EAP 7.4?

Tags: jboss, classloader, jboss7.x

My webapp running on JBoss EAP 7.4 is having problems locating certain classes.  When I run, I see the following in the log:

> 2022-08-02 14:30:52,387 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (default
> task-2) **Failed to define class
> org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataSplitPolicy** in Module
> "deployment.dbp.rest-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link
> org/apache/phoenix/schema/MetaDataSplitPolicy (Module
> "deployment.dbp.rest-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader):
> **Failed to link
> org/apache/phoenix/schema/SplitOnLeadingVarCharColumnsPolicy** (Module
> "deployment.dbp.rest-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader):
> **org/apache/phoenix/compat/hbase/CompatSteppingSplitPolicy**

`MetaDataSplitPolicy` and `SplitOnLeadingVarCharColumnsPolicy` are present in our war file, but `CompatSteppingSplitPolicy` is not.  The `/usr/lib/phoenix/phoenix-hbase-compat-2.4.1-5.1.2.jar` file contains `CompatSteppingSplitPolicy`.  [Adding external modules directories in JBoss EAP 6/7](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/195733) tells how the classpath be extended to deployed content reference directories and files external to the installation.  I modified my .bashrc accordingly, and the log file now includes:

```
module.path = /opt/jboss-eap-7.4/modules:/usr/lib/phoenix/phoenix-hbase-compat-2.4.1-5.1.2.jar:/usr/lib/phoenix/*
```

Unfortunately, I still get the same error.  What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

why not adding the jar in your war ? otherwise you need to add a dependency on that module in your war

Comment: For whatever reason, adding the following to my pom.xml does not add the jar to my war:   <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
                <artifactId>phoenix-hbase-compat-2.4.1</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.2</version>
<!--                <scope>runtime</scope>-->
            </dependency>

Comment: That definitely seems strange. Do you have some kind of filtering set in the `maven-war-plugin`?

Comment: @James - I was able to get the jar into the war - it turns out I didn't do the dependency right in the child pom.xml.  D'oh.